# Dynamically type casting to numeric in dplyr and sparklyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

The jist of this question is that I have some R code which works fine on a local data frame, but fails on a Spark data frame, even if otherwise the two tables are identical.

In R, given a dataframe of all character columns, one can dynamically type cast all the columns to numeric that can be safely converted to numeric with the following code:

```
require(dplyr)
require(varhandle)
require(sparklyr)

checkNumeric <- function(column)
{
  column %>% as.data.frame %>% .[,1] %>% varhandle::check.numeric(.) %>% all
}

typeCast <- function(df)
{ 
  columns <- colnames(df)
  numericIdx <- df %>% mutate(across(columns, checkNumeric)) %>% .[1,]
  doThese <- columns[which(numericIdx==T)]
  
  df <- df %>% mutate_at(all_of(vars(doThese)), as.numeric)
  return(df)
}
```

For a trivial example, one could run:

```
df <- iris
df$Sepal.Length <- as.character(df$Sepal.Length)
newDF <- df %>% typeCast
class(df$Sepal.Length)
class(newDF$Sepal.Length)
```

Now, this code will not work on a dataset like `starwars`, which has composite columns. But for other dataframes, I would expect this code to work just fine on a Spark data frame. It doesn't. That is:

```
sc <- spark_connect('yarn', config=config) # define your Spark configuration somewhere, that's outside the scope of this question
df <- copy_to(sc, iris, "iris")
newDF <- df %>% typeCast
```

Will fail with the following error.

`Error in .[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`

When debugging, if we try to run this code:

```
columns <- colnames(df)
df %>% mutate(across(columns, checkNumeric))
```

This error is returned:
Error in UseMethod("escape") :
no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of class "function"

What gives? Why would the code work fine on a local data frame, but not a Spark data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an exact solution per se, but I did find a workaround.

```
typeCheckPartition <- function(df)
{
  require(dplyr)
  require(varhandle)
  checkNumeric <- function(column)
  {
    column %>% as.data.frame %>% .[,1] %>% varhandle::check.numeric(.) %>% all
  }
  
  # this works on non-spark data frames
  columns <- colnames(df)
  numericIdx <- df %>% mutate(across(all_of(columns), checkNumeric)) %>% .[1,]
  
  return(numericIdx)
}

typeCastSpark <- function(df, max_partitions = 1000, undo_coalesce = T)
{
  # numericIdxDf will have these dimensions: num_partition rows x num_columns
  # so long as num_columns is not absurd, this coalesce should make collect a safe operation
  num_partitions <- sdf_num_partitions(df)
  if (num_partitions > max_partitions)
  {
    undo_coalesce <- T && undo_coalesce
    df <- df %>% sdf_coalesce(max_partitions)
  } else
  {
    undo_coalesce <- F
  }
  
  columns <- colnames(df)
  numericIdxDf <- df %>% spark_apply(typeCheckPartition, packages=T) %>% collect
  numericIdx <- numericIdxDf %>% as.data.frame %>% apply(2, all)
  
  doThese <- columns[which(numericIdx==T)]
  df <- df %>% mutate_at(all_of(vars(doThese)), as.numeric)
  
  if (undo_coalesce)
    df <- df %>% sdf_repartition(num_partitions)
  
  return(df)
}
```

Just run the typeCastSpark function against your dataframe and it will type cast all of the columns to numeric (that can be).